# Mason Says, Commas

Tags: clauses, commas, reported-speech

In this [sentence](http://www.myfoxorlando.com/story/25970683/defense-attorney-cheney-mason-writes-book-about-casey-anthony):

> This book comes three years after the verdict, ***and Mason says after lots of prodding from publishers***.

are commas missing around  "Mason says"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

*Mason says* is clearly a parenthetical comment identifying the source of the second clause, which is a parallel construction informing us that "The book comes after lots of prodding from publishers."

Actually I think it would read better if the entire second clause were parenthesized and "Mason says" offset in commas, thus:

> The book comes three years after the verdict (and, Mason says, after lots of prodding from publishers).